# apache and python command line arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to setup up psdash with apache.  PSDASH requires commandline variables to be passed to it and I was wondering how this was acheved within apache.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

psdash is a standalone app and doesn't need a fronting web server. Just start psdash as usual and it will serve the web interface on port 5000 by default.

For more info:

```
psdash --help
```